# SQLite database backup ASP.NET Core file locked

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, .net-core, hangfire, sqlite-net

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 application that uses SQLite. I have a recurring Hangfire job that I'd like to use to back up the database using the online backup API of SQLite. Finally, I'd like to upload the backup database file to Azure blob storage. Code:

```
public void CreateBackup()
{
    string backupPath = string.Empty;
    using (var originalConnection = new SqliteConnection(this.configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")))
    using (var backupConnection = new SqliteConnection(this.configuration.GetConnectionString("BackupDatabase")))
    {
        originalConnection.Open();
        originalConnection.BackupDatabase(backupConnection);
        backupPath = backupConnection.DataSource;
    }

    BlobClient client = new BlobClient(this.configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureBackup"), "tanusitvanytar", $"database-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}");
    client.Upload(backupPath);
}
```

But when the upload is executed I get an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file.

The using block is supposed to close the connection to the backup database, so what is still using it? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you double check that the backup file have been created?

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin Yes, the backup file itself seems fine.

Comment: The SQLite provider pools connections (after v6.0), to improve connection speed but keeps connections open. So either disable pooling by adding `Pooling=false` to the connection string or call `SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools()` at the point where you want them to be closed. See the details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26580).

Comment: That was a great catch, thanks. If you add it as an actual answer, I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either disable pooling by adding

`Pooling=false` to the connection string

or call

`SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools();`

at the point where you want the connection to be closed.